# different result of event.getCreator() when on kitkat and lollipop

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-calendar

```
event.getCreator();
```

does not return `displayName`

> (displayName:Qamran Rajput,email:qami1502@gmail.com,self:true) Kitkat HTC DESIRE 820
>
> (email:qami1502@gmail.com,self:true) lollipop LG G3

Both using same Google Play Services Versions Can any one suggest how to tackle this issue please.

```
private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException, ParseException {
            // List the next 10 events from the primary calendar.
            DateTime now = new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            List<String> eventStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
            Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                    .setMaxResults(30)
                    .setTimeMin(now)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .execute();
            List<Event> items = events.getItems();

            for (Event event : items) {

                String id = event.getId();
                DateTime start = event.getStart().getDateTime();
                if (start == null) {
                    // All-day events don't have start times, so just use
                    // the start date.
                    start = event.getStart().getDate();
                }
                DateTime end = event.getEnd().getDateTime();

                String eventTitle = event.getSummary();
                String Creator = String.valueOf(event.getCreator());//string displayName:Qamran Rajput,email:qami1502@gmail.com,self:true}

}
}
```

Comment: The API call you provided seems to be good. It's also indicated in the documentation that `Events.list` will only provide the other creator attributes if its available. Are the 2 devices using different Google Play Services version installed? That may contribute to the issue.

Comment: Also are you checking the same event on both versions?

Comment: @adjuremods Yes Both devices are using the same version of Google Play Services. and if they are available only then its been returned on kitkat.

Comment: @luc Yes i am checking same event on both versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calendar Api doesn't return creator name for Lollipop and Marshmallow. So you can write:

```
if (creatorName == null) {
creatorName = "";
}
```

To avoid any null pointer exceptions

Regards